# salesforfce-enterprise-wsdl is specific to organization?

Tags: api, wsdl, salesforce

I have created two developer accounts in salesforce.
I want to know whether I can use a single "Enterprise WSDL" for salesforce api to connect to both salesforce accounts.

I got the doubt because of their link for downloading wsdl file.
The link name is "**Generate** Enterprise WSDL".

Answer (score 1):

The wsdl's will only be the same if the model (the custom objects and fields) in both orgs is identical.

Comment: I am using api to work with standard objects (user, profile, etc...)  only. So I can take one wsdl file and it can be used for all organization right?

Comment: @habeebperwad, if you're only working with standard objects, why not just use the Partner WSDL?

Comment: @JCD Actually I don't know what is partner wsdl. I googled it. But i didn't get any answer. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618782/regarding-salesforce-partner-wsdl#comment17014251_12618782

Comment: @habeebperwad http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_partner.htm - think of it as a generic Salesforce WSDL, while the Enterprise WSDL is a more specialized WSDL specific to one particular org.

Comment: field level security & other settings can make the enterprise WSDL different between orgs, even just for standard objects & fields. If you want a WSDL that can be used across multiple orgs, use the partner WSDL (or use the REST API)

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise WSDL:

It is a strongly typed wsdl.

Which tells that,once you have generated this wsdl in a specific org then it is supposed to connect to that org only. The reason is, it is schema oriented. If both orgs are having same schema then it works to connect.

Partner WSDL:

It is loosely typed wsdl.

Once you have generated this wsdl in one org then we can connect to any other org.

But both wsdl needs UserName, Password, Security token and end point URL while integrating.